# Transposing the data from csv file to csv using python or Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, csv

I am working on data having four columns and 912500 rows in csv format. I need to transpose the data in each column to 365 columns and 2500 rows in separate csv file. eg.

Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4

1     33  36   38

2      25  18   56

365    -4  -3  10

366    -11  20 35

367    12   18 27 
.
.

730    26   36 27
.
.

.
912500  20 37 42

Desired output

```
Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4 Col5 .....Col 365
```

1   33    25...........................-4

2  -11   12  .......................  26

3

4.............

5............
  .
  .

2500............................

Please do advise me how to write a script for this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question is really confusing, I think you need to format and refine what you're asking a bit better.  You want the every 91~92 (365/4) rows to joined together into a 365 column row?

Comment: He wants to take Column X of original Data (912500 rows) and then reformat this to a matrix of size 2500*365 (=912500 entries as well). @Sam: One column of original data `A` can be selected like this: `A(:,1)`, then you need to use `reshape()` -> https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html it's quite simple.

Comment: You can do that reshape in Python using Numpy.

Comment: Thanks every one for replying. I was able to reshape the data in desired matrix. Appreciated your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NumPy as suggested in the comments, but, just in case you want to code it yourself, here's one approach you could take:

- You can read the file one line at a time
- Split each line using the comma as the separator
- Discard the "row count" (first element of the list you get as a result of the split operation). You will have to maintain your own row count.
- Copy the remaining elements to another list until you have 365 elements (including row count)
- Write this list as CSV to the output file. You can use Python's built-in CSV writer (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)
- Repeat until the whole input file has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader` will create an iterator that reads the csv row by row. You can then feed that into `itertools.chain` which iterates each row in turn, outputing individual columns. Now that you have a stream of columns, you can group them into new rows of the size you want. There are several ways to rebuild those rows and I used `itertools.groupby` in my example.

```
import itertools
import csv

def groupby_count(iterable, count):
    counter = itertools.count()
    for _, grp in itertools.groupby(iterable, lambda _: next(counter)//count):
        yield tuple(grp)

def reshape_csv(in_filename, out_filename, colsize):
    with open(in_filename) as infile, open(out_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
        col_iter = itertools.chain.from_iterable(reader)
        writer.writerows(groupby_count(col_iter, colsize))
```

And here's an example script to test. I used fewer columns, though:

```
import os
infn = "intest.csv"
outfn = "outtest.csv"
orig_colsize = 4
new_colsize = 15

# test input file
with open(infn, "w") as infp:
    for i in range(32):
        infp.write(' '.join('c{0:02d}_{1:02d}'.format(i,j) for j in range(4)) + '\n')

# remove stale output file
try:
    os.remove(outfn)
except OSError:
    pass

# run it and print
reshape_csv(infn, outfn, new_colsize)
print('------- test output ----------')
print(open(outfn).read())
```

Answer (score 0):

What follows is tested against a fake data file, it worked OK for me but ymmv...
please see the inline comments for a description of the workings

```
import csv

# we open the data file and put its content in data, that is a list of lists
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]

# the following idiom transpose a list of lists
transpose = zip(*data)

# I use Python 3, hence zip is a generator and I have to throw away using next()
# the first element, i.e., the column of the row numbers
next(transpose)

# I enumerate transpose, obtaininig the data column by column    
for nc, column in enumerate(transpose):

    # I prepare for writing to a csv file
    with open('trans%d.csv'%nc, 'w') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)

        # here, we have an idiom, sort of..., please see
        #   http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.it/2013/08/how-grouper-works.html
        # for the reason why what we enumerate are the rows of your output file
        for nr, row in enumerate(zip(*[iter(column)]*365)):
            writer.writerow([nr+1,*row])
```